# More feature leads to worse result in Random forest and adaboosting method

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, adaboost

This is a problem that I met in real regression analysis using real data. I am using Random forest as well as Adaboost method to do regression. X has 5 dimension and y has 1 dimension. The sample size is 110k. However, if I add more feature into X (X has more dimension). Then the out of sample test of the model is reduced by 30%.

My knowledge says this is very unlikely to happen but this indeed happened. I am wondering the underlying mechanisms and how shall we deal with this problem.

Comment: i agree with you this is less likely to happen. what is mtry? if you set low, does it still happen?

Comment: @hxd1011 Instead of using R I am using python so there is no such a parameters called mtry. But I checked python and I believe(correct me if I am wrong)mtry is called min_samples_split, which is set default to be 2

Comment: min_samples_split is definitely not mtry. mtry means random columns to build a tree. min_samples_split, means when you build a tree, if you should continue to split

Comment: @hxd1011 Thanks! The default value of mtry is the number of features. I will try the result by reducing the value. Intuitively, why we can get better result by reducing the value of mtry in this case?

Comment: you may not get better results by reducing that number. but if you reduce that number, it is kind of equal to you reduce number of features, which would helpful to see what will happen for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Classifiers work generally better with lower dimensionalities, but of higher quality. Maybe the additional features are too noisy and are detrimental to the learning?

What about the training accuracy, does it go down as well as the testing accuracy? If not, then this is surely a case of overfitting. This might happen when the classifier learns from the noise.

In order to reduce the noise, you might try dimensionality reduction techniques, such as PCA or autoencoders (I strongly suggest for autoencoders, as they learn nonlinear mappings). Then you can run your classification algorithm on the learned codes.